# Loop is not working properly for Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

i'm trying to run the following piece of code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/SoumyaPandey/Desktop/Galytix/Scrapers/data_ingestion/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/Pages/default.aspx')
years_urls = list()
#ctl00_ctl33_g_8893c127_d0ad_40f2_9856_d85936172f35_years --> id for the year filter
years_elements = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl33_g_8893c127_d0ad_40f2_9856_d85936172f35_years').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for i in range(len(years_elements)):
    years_urls.append(years_elements[i].get_attribute('href'))
newslinks = list()
for k in range(len(years_urls)):
    url = years_urls[k]
    driver.get(url)
    #link-detailpage --> id for the newslinks in each year
    news = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('link-detailpage')
    for j in range(len(news)):
        newslinks.append(news[j].find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href'))
```

when I run this code, the newslinks list is empty at the end of execution. But if I run it line by line, by assigning the value of 'k' one by one, on my own, it runs successfully.

Where am I going wrong in the logic. Please help.

Comment: there is no `'link-detailpage'` tag value, where do you see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is too much redundant code. I would suggest use either linear `xpath` or `css selector` to identify the elements.
However some of the pages the new link not appeared you need to handle this using `try..except`.

Since you need to navigate each url I would suggest use  [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) `WebDriverWait()`

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/SoumyaPandey/Desktop/Galytix/Scrapers/data_ingestion/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/Pages/default.aspx")
allyears=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div#ctl00_ctl33_g_8893c127_d0ad_40f2_9856_d85936172f35_years a")))
yearsurl=[url.get_attribute("href") for url in allyears]

newslinks = list()
for yr in yearsurl:
  driver.get(yr)
  try:
    for element in WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.link-detailpage >a"))):
        newslinks.append(element.get_attribute("href"))
  except:
    continue
print(newslinks)
```

**OutPut**:

```
['https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/march/Pages/a-problem-solved-at-a-rate-of-knots-the-latest-Top-Story-available-on-CNHIndustrial-com.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/march/Pages/CNH-Industrial-acquires-a-minority-stake-in-Augmenta.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/march/Pages/CNH-Industrial-presents-YOUNIVERSE.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/march/Pages/Calling-of-the-Annual-General-Meeting.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/march/Pages/CNH-Industrial-completes-minority-investment-in-Monarch-Tractor.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/February/Pages/CNH-Industrial-N-V--announces-the-extension-by-one-additional-year-to-March-2026-of-its-syndicated-credit-facility.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/February/Pages/Working-for-a-safer-future-with-World-Class-Manufacturing.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/February/Pages/Behind-the-Wheel-CNH-Industrial-supports-the-growing-hemp-industry-in-North-America.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/February/Pages/CNH-Industrial-employees-in-Italy-to-receive-contractual-bonus-for-2020-results.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/February/Pages/2020-Fourth-Quarter-and-Full-Year-Results.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/january/Pages/The-Iveco-Defence-Vehicles-plant-in-Sete-Lagoas,-Brazil-and-the-New-Holland-Agriculture-facility-in-Croix,-France.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/january/Pages/CNH-Industrial-to-announce-2020-Fourth-Quarter-and-Full-Year-financial-results-on-February-3-2021.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/january/Pages/CNH-Industrial-publishes-its-2021-Corporate-Calendar.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/january/Pages/Iveco-Defence-Vehicles-supplies-third-generation-protected-military-GTF8x8-(ZLK-15t)-trucks-to-the-German-Army.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/january/Pages/STEYR-New-Holland-Agriculture-CASE-Construction-Equipment-and-FPT-Industrial-win-prestigious-2020-Good-Design%C2%AE-Awards.aspx', 'https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/2021/january/Pages/CNH-Industrial-completes-the-acquisition-of-four-divisions-of-CEG-in-South-Africa.aspx',so on...]
```

---

**Update**:

If you don't want use webdriverwait which is best practice then use `time.sleep()` since page needs some time to load and element should be visible before interacting it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/SoumyaPandey/Desktop/Galytix/Scrapers/data_ingestion/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/Pages/default.aspx')
years_urls = list()
time.sleep(5)
#ctl00_ctl33_g_8893c127_d0ad_40f2_9856_d85936172f35_years --> id for the year filter
years_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="ctl00_ctl33_g_8893c127_d0ad_40f2_9856_d85936172f35_years"]//a')
for i in range(len(years_elements)):
    years_urls.append(years_elements[i].get_attribute('href'))
print(years_urls)
newslinks = list()
for k in range(len(years_urls)):
    url = years_urls[k]
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)    
    news = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="link-detailpage"]/a')
    for j in range(len(news)):
        newslinks.append(news[j].get_attribute('href'))
        
print(newslinks)
```

Comment: what if I don't want to use the webdriverwait() ? 
without it the code fails. And what is incorrect in my piece of code ?

Comment: @SoumyaPandey : 1) It is best practice when you interact with browser use explicit wait so that code always sync with application. 2)If you see your code you have identified parent tag and then again child tag based on parent tag. you can make it simple way to identify child element with either `xpath` or `css selector` which helps to reduce execution time. Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: right, I understand these points. But shouldn't the code work? I mean even if the execution time is greater than your suggested code's time, it should work, right? But it doesn't. at the end I get an empty newslist.

Comment: @SoumyaPandey : SO contributor can provide you better solution for the query. However I have updated my answer with `time.sleep()` . Try and let me know how this goes?

Comment: sure. it works fine! :) thanks a ton!! 
I applied the same logic of using webdriverwait to other websites, but they kept on giving a timeout exception.

Comment: example : driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/SoumyaPandey/Desktop/Galytix/Scrapers/data_ingestion/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.autoliv.com/news-and-media/press-releases')
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'cc-reject-Btn')))
driver.find_element(By.ID,'cc-reject-Btn').click()

all_pages = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'ul.pager a')))

Comment: ^ this gave a time out exception. I tried to apply the same logic to proceed with other websites.

Comment: It seems another website please post a separate question for that.if the above answer resolve your initial query please mark this as accepted and vote for it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a popup asking you to accept cookies that you need to click beforehand.

Add this to your script:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept")))
driver.find_element_by_id("CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept").click()
```

So the final result will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/SoumyaPandey/Desktop/Galytix/Scrapers/data_ingestion/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.cnhindustrial.com/en-us/media/press_releases/Pages/default.aspx')

# this part is added, together with the necessary imports
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept")))
driver.find_element_by_id("CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept").click()

years_urls = list()
#ctl00_ctl33_g_8893c127_d0ad_40f2_9856_d85936172f35_years --> id for the year filter
# years_elements = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ctl33_g_8893c127_d0ad_40f2_9856_d85936172f35_years")
years_elements = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl33_g_8893c127_d0ad_40f2_9856_d85936172f35_years').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for i in range(len(years_elements)):
    years_urls.append(years_elements[i].get_attribute('href'))
newslinks = list()
for k in range(len(years_urls)):
    url = years_urls[k]
    driver.get(url)
    #link-detailpage --> id for the newslinks in each year
    news = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('link-detailpage')
    for j in range(len(news)):
        newslinks.append(news[j].find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: this isn't working. the newslinks is still coming empty.